# Error Connecting to Docker hub

Tags: docker

I have created a docker hub account and trying to connect on it to push an image. I am getting the following error:

```
>>>docker login -u <username> -p <password>

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I run this and i got the following message:

```
>>>curl https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}
```

Also:

```
>>> env | grep -i proxy
```

gave no result(means that i dont have proxy settings??)

```
>>> docker version
Client:
Version:      1.12.3
API version:  1.24
Go version:   go1.6.3
Git commit:   6b644ec
Built:        Wed Oct 26 22:01:48 2016
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
Version:      1.12.3
API version:  1.24
Go version:   go1.6.3
Git commit:   6b644ec
Built:        Wed Oct 26 22:01:48 2016
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Any idea how to overpass that?

Comment: while you `Error response from daemon:` it is useless to try anything

Comment: Didnt understand your comment. what do u mean? no solution?

Comment: your `docker login` fails with `Error response from daemon: ...` so any other command will fail, as you are not connected

Comment: a) What o.s. and what docker version are you using? b) What is saying your docker log file? c) Ask your network administrators if if you need a proxy to reach internet.

Answer (score 29):

Modified DNS server setting to 8.8.8.8 and it worked.

[image]

Comment: An article for the same https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-pcs-dns-settings-windows-10

Comment: didn't work with me! why do you think it might help?

Answer (score 24):

In my case (Ubuntu 16.04, Docker 18.01.0), I could solve it by setting the proxy like below.

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
$ sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http_proxy.conf
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://<your_proxy_ip>:<your_proxy_port>/"
$ sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/https_proxy.conf
[Service]
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://<your_proxy_ip>:<your_proxy_port>/"
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score 7):

This issue sometimes reoccurs randomly on docker:

If you get this error and are not blocked by a proxy, perform the following steps:

1. Restart docker-machine

   ```
   docker-machine restart default
   ```
2. Reset to default env

   ```
   eval $(docker-machine env default)
   ```

If you try again, you may find that everything just works fine.

Comment: it worked for me in Windows using Git bash itself. Thanks!

Comment: Just doing step one seemed to solve it for me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

If you are in Linux. You can change `nameserver` in `/etc/resolv.conf`. 
Set the nameserver to `8.8.8.8`. 
Restart the docker demon. `sudo systemctl restart docker`.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue and then resolved the issue by configured the docker environment http_proxy, because i'm behind a corp proxy:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#http-proxy

Comment: It took 3 days to find your suggestion. Works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue for win 10 pro. After both changes, I was able to log-in and pull images.

1. If you want to use windows as a container.  Right-click docker whale icon and -> switch to windows container.

[image: windows as container]

2. If you want to use Linux as a container. (Your machine must have a
   password for login)

   - Right-click docker whale icon and -> switch to Linux container.
   - Go to Settings click shared drives and select D or C or both.
   - Enter the windows user password and save changes.

[image: linux as container]

Answer (score 2):

Mac High Sierra / Docker 18:

In my case I had to sign out my Docker User (directly in the Docker menu).

Answer (score 2):

I just switched from Mac to corporate Windows 10 machine, so getting to the Docker GUI was not obvious, I had to expand the carret ("^"), then right click on Docker icon:

[image: Docker GUI]

I chose Settings in the right click menu to bring up the Docker GUI.  In the Docker GUI, I clicked on Proxies and added the (actual) address of my company proxy:

[image: Docker Proxy]

Also of note, I was [able to login to our internal repository and Docker Hub](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/7uq22t/question_multiple_registries_how_to/) so that I could pull images from both places - so my config.json file looked (something) like this:

```
{
  "auths": {
    "company.internal.rep.com:9000": {},
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
  },
  "HttpHeaders": {
    "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.09.2 (windows)"
  },
  "credsStore": "wincred"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My solution was to specify the correct repository parameter. I've registered at hub.docker.com. So I've added it as parameter to docker login command:

docker login -u username -p password hub.docker.com

If you still have an error, please check that it is not a network issue with your proxy by using the following command:

curl -I -x PROXY_USERID:PROXY_PASSWORD@YOUR_PROXY:PROXY_PORT http://google.com

As well I've used ip address instead of host name to specify my proxy to exclude DNS errors.

If you got error with curl, then you need configure docker http_proxy and https_proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Docker 18 / Windows 10:

In Settings > Network > DNS Sever - Select fixed and enter your DNS Server IP.

Answer (score 1):

In Docker settings -> Network, I switched the DNS Server setting to "Fixed" as in the screenshot below and it worked!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Linux (Ubuntu)

- Edit network interface

  ```
  nano /etc/network/interfaces
  ```
- Replace dns-nameservers some_ip_address to dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

  ```
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
  ```
- Restart networking

  ```
  sudo systemctl restart networking
  ```

> Note: If google dns (dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
>   ) is not working use open dns (dns-nameservers 208.67.222.222)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, i just restarted the docker service and it works fine for me

$ sudo service docker restart

$ docker login

Answer (score 0):

Open the docker whale icon and restart docker.

Answer (score 0):

There's no proxy in my setup so this was resolved with a simple docker restart. This can be done easily via cli or gui

Answer (score 0):

Define in your host operating system's network configuration a standard gateway for the docker adapter and also one for DNS. This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

i solve to this problem with change the dns to `8.8.8.8`
and run this commands:

```
sudo systemctl deamon-reload

sudo systemctl restart docker*
```

the `docker*` restart whole docker.